# Arabic Language Support for Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, multilingual

I am researching on providing Arabic language support to my website. 
I found that http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/  in Spring MVC how can we can load the appropriate message bundles.

But for Arabic language we need a full mirror image of the screen.
I found some great info from http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2010/7-tips-and-techniques-for-multi-lingual-website-accessibility.

I am planning to use class for configuring styling.

My doubt is what is the best practice to achieve the following in page:

```
<set var = "currentLocale" value=${pageContext.response.locale}>

if(currentLocale== 'ar'){
      <html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
}else if(currentLocale== 'en'){
     <html lang="en">
}

if(currentLocale== 'ar'){
     <body class="styleForArabic">
}else if(currentLocale== 'en'){
      <body >
}
```

Can we get current locale in jsp OR do we need to set any variable from java and pass as modal. 
Is there any dependency with Spring Security? I have implemented Spring Security in my app.

Is there any out of box support in Spring for handling these requirements.

Comment: did you find a solution for this issue?